# Change order of integral of $I = \int_{-6}^{3} {dx} \int_{x-3}^{1 - \frac{x^2}{9}} {f(x,y)dy}$

Tags: integration

I was asked this question:

> Change order of integral of $I = \int_{-6}^{3} {dx} \int_{x-3}^{1 - \frac{x^2}{9}} {f(x,y)dy}$

So I did the graph, and figured I needed three seperate areas and I came up with :

> $I = \int_{-9}^{-3}dy \int_{-6}^{y+3}{f(x,y)dx}
> + \int_{-3}^{0}dy \int_{-\sqrt{9-9y}}^{y+3}{f(x,y)dx}  
> + \int_{0}^{1}dy \int_{-\sqrt{9-9y}}^{\sqrt{9+9y}}{f(x,y)dx}    $

But this is obviously not logical.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As a brief hint/tip/piece of advice, I would try and sketch out the region suggested by the limits of integration, and then figure out the new limits when integrating with respect to x first.

Comment: That's what I did though...

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that. Oh well, I'm stumped then.

Comment: Why is that not logical?  I got the same.

Comment: What bothered me is the 3rd integral in my solution, repeated bounds regarding $x$.